# Cross-validation with CatBoostRegressor never stop

Tags: python, scikit-learn, catboost

I use this code to do Cross-validation with catboost.However, it has been 10 hours, and the console is still output, and the cross-validation is obviously more than 5 rounds.
What is the problem?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import catboost
# from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV

train_data = pd.read_csv('train.txt',sep='\t')
test_data = pd.read_csv('test.txt',sep='\t')
X = train_data.iloc[:,:-1]
y = train_data['target']
model = catboost.CatBoostRegressor(
                           loss_function="RMSE",
                           eval_metric="RMSE",
                           task_type="GPU",
                           learning_rate=0.01,
                           iterations=10000,
                           random_seed=42,
                           od_type="Iter",
                           depth=10,
                           early_stopping_rounds=50
                          )
rfecv = RFECV(estimator = model,cv = 5,scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error')
rfecv.fit(X, y)
df = pd.DataFrame(rfecv.predict(test_data))
df.to_csv("my.txt", index=False, header=False)
```

Then I stop the program,when I change iterations to 100,I found that the console has iterated a total of 161 times and stopped.In my opinion, it should be stopped after 5 cross-validation, but in fact it has not stopped after 5 times.
Why is it like this?

Comment: `RFECV (cv = 5)`, this way of writing misleads me that the cross-validation will stop after 5 times.

Comment: No, the stopping criterion is not clear from the docs (if it stops when local minima is reached or after searching all the feature subsets for a global one), but it is definitely not after fitting 5 folds. It's fitting 5 folds for all feature subsets until stopping criterion is reached. In addition running 10000 boosted iterators may be unnecessary.

Comment: Actually the reason for me to ask you in the first place was to show you that brute force testing all possible combination may result in a better result then recursive elimination, which could be suboptimal. See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64449113/why-does-the-standardscaler-have-different-effects-under-different-number-of-fea/64458489#64458489). But it could be computationally prohibitive for larger datasets. In such situation data cleaning and feature engineering yields better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several easy steps in trying to remedy this problem:

1. Reduce `iterations` to a more meaningful 1000, or even 300 if you still have time issues.
2. Reduce `cv` to 3 eg
3. Check with a smaller subset of your data if it finishes within a reasonable amount of time. Then estimate with the whole dataset -- assuming the algo will scale "linearly" -- if you're comfortable with the time.

Notice, `RFECV` is a greedy algo, pruning weakest features one at a time, which may lead to a problem if a local minimum is reached.

Comment: This help me a lot.